# Como manter os elementos do site no mesmo local o tempo todo?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<div id="geral">

<p class="texto_grande_titulo">...</p> 
                          ...
 </div>
```

No CSS:

```
div#geral{ background-image:url(../imagens/borda.png);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 802px;
    height: 719px;
    margin:auto;
    margin-top: 160px;
    }
```

E quero saber como posso fazer para essa div permanecer parada no mesmo local de forma que ao rolar para baixo a div não acompanhe.Como o site do stack, podem perceber que ao dar zoom ou afastar todos os elementos da página ficam no mesmo local, o que não acontece no meu site, qual a melhor forma de fazer isso sem utilizar bootstrap?

Comment: Está meio difícil de entender o que vc quer... Vc precisa de um menu sempre fixo no topo?

Answer (score 2):

```css
div#geral{ background-image:url('http://kithomepage.com/images/Imagem003.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width: 802px;
    height: 719px;
    position:fixed; 
    top:100px;
    left:0
}
```

```html
<div id="geral">

<p class="texto_grande_titulo">TextoParagrafo TextoParagrafo TextoParagrafo TextoParagrafo TextoParagrafo</p> 
                          TextoDiv TextoDiv TextoDiv TextoDiv 
 </div>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
<p>bla bla bla</p>
```

O position: fixed; irá fixar a posição do elemento na coordenada que você definir.
A medida que a página é rolada, o elemento continua fixo na posição que você definiu e o conteúdo da página rola normalmente.

A posição de um elemento com posicionamento fixo (position: fixed;) é definida em relação à "viewport", ou seja, a própria janela do browser. Quando rolamos a página, a "viewport" não muda, portanto o elemento vai ficar exatamente onde está.

O valor fixed no atributo position funciona em todos os navegadores, mas no caso de Internet Explorer só funciona na versão 7 e superiores.

Para que funcione tem que se declarar um DOCTYPE!.

Browsers de dispositivos móveis têm um apoio instável para fixar. Leia mais sobre a situação (ingles) http://bradfrost.com/blog/mobile/fixed-position/.

Comment: Com jquery pode ver em http://jsfiddle.net/Tgm6Y/1/

Comment: Mas nesse caso a div é acompanhada de acordo com o scroll do mouse ou a barra de rolagem do site, eu quero que ele apenas fique fixo mas sem que seja acompanhado por esses dois itens.